# Custom module Pager does not work with Ajax filter

Tags: 7, ajax, paging

My custom module uses an Ajax enabled drop down to allow users to filter images. There is also a pager attached to the query. The pager works fine when all the data is displayed i.e. no filter applied but after applying a filter, clicking a pager button just gives a white screen.

Here is my code.

```
function view_colouring_sheets($form, $form_state){
$query = db_select('field_data_field_image','fi')->extend('PagerDefault');
$query->join('node','n','n.nid = fi.entity_id');
$query->fields('fi');
$query->fields('n',array('title'));
$query->limit(20);
if($form_state['input']['tid']){
    $query->condition('entity_id',  colouring_sheets_filtered_tid($form_state['input']['tid']),'in');
}
$images = $query->execute()->fetchAll();


$output = array(
    '#theme'=>'image_matrix',
    '#type'=>'markup',
    '#images'=>$images,
    '#title'=>'Colouring Sheets',
    '#pager'=>theme('pager'),
    '#filter_form'=>  drupal_render(drupal_get_form('image_filter_form')),
);

return $output;
}




function colouring_sheets_filtered_tid($tid){
    $query = db_select('field_data_field_image_category','ic');
    $query->condition('field_image_category_tid',$tid);
    $query->fields('ic');
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    $term_array = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $term_array[] = $row->entity_id;
    }
    return $term_array;
}

function image_filter_form($form, $form_state){
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(18);
    $terms_array = array();
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $terms_array[$term->tid] = $term->name;
    }
    $form['tid'] = array(
        '#type'=>'select',
        '#options'=>$terms_array,
        '#required'=>TRUE,
        '#title'=>'Fitler Images',
        '#ajax'=>array(
            'method'=>'replace',
            'wrapper'=>'image_matrix',
            'callback'=>'view_colouring_sheets',
            'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => 'Images Loading'),
            'effect'=>'fade',
        ),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Where is the image_matrix div located?  not seeing it in your form html anywhere

Comment: Also is this a separate module and showing us functions?  Drupal conventions would have all your functions named modulename_function.  Your functions are named differently.  not that it will cause any issues.

Comment: After further digging around different forums, I found the answer. This is a bug in Drupal and which still exists in Drupal 8. They are going to try a fix in 8 and if successful will port it to Drupal 7. The issue is that after refreshing a page via ajax which contains a Pager all the links are built around the current url which in this case would be system/ajax which is why the pager then stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a sort of workaround.  It requires storing the result of `current_path()` in a JS setting variable, and rewriting the path in JS when the pager is regenerated.

Sample code:

```
php
// building an ajax form...
global $base_path;
$settings = array(
    'my_module' => array(
    'my_path' => $base_path . current_path(),
  ),
);
drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
```

That will make the current page's path available in your JavaScript file to manipulate.  There are still kinks though, especially with AJAX filtering and AJAX paging all at once.  I will update this once I resolve all those kinks.